# In a sql query, is there an order to declare the Join?

Tags: sql

I have always had the doubt if it is the same or if it has consequences to make a query in the following ways, or if there is any standard to follow when establishing the order of a join depending on whether or not it is the table that has the key foreign.

```
Alumno                   Escuela
——————                   ——————
Id_alumno                Id_escuela
Nombre                   Nombre
Id_escuela               ——————
```

1:

```
Select e.Nombre, a.id_alumno, a.nombre
From escuela e, alumno a
Where a.Id_escuela = e.Id_escuela
```

2:

```
Select e.Nombre, a.id_alumno, a.nombre
From alumno a, escuela e
Where e.Id_escuela = a.Id_escuela
```

And the same if I were using the reserved word `JOIN`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

The order of the columns in the comparison *does not matter*.

SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  That means that a SQL query describes the result set, but does not specify how the results are generated.  The SQL compiler and optimizer take care of handling the execution plan.

The two conditions specify exactly the same results, and so should have no impact on the execution plan.

That said, you should be using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The order is not important because the vast majority of modern databases automatically reorder joins according to what is most optimal for the query. You can verify this yourself by examining the execution plan of your different versions of the query. You will see that in all cases, the execution plan is the same.

For this reason, unless the order affects the result of the query itself (which is not the case in your example, but it would be if it were a LEFT JOIN for example), simply write the query to make it work for you. readable and easy to understand. The database will take care of reorganizing the clauses of your query automatically to maximize performance.

With this in mind, I recommend that you avoid using implicit join notation. Rather, it favors explicit joins, which are easier to understand, especially when the query wraps multiple tables with multiple joins:

```
select e.nombre, a.id_alumno, a.nombre
from escuela e
join alumno a on a.id_escuela = e.id_escuela
```

Comment: I really don't get it. You are answering **your own** question here? Why did you ask, then? This seems like a shameless attempt to "game the system". Downvote from me, with prejudice - I invite others to do the same.